# bash: bad flag in substitute command with escaped slashes

Tags: bash

I want to scan all files and replace all instances. However, when $my_var is read from the command line input via

`read -p ' Input React route ' my_var`

and I pass `\/HomePage\/`

it throws : `sed: 1: "s/<Route component={P ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'H'`

full bash script:

```
read -p ' Input React route ' my_var
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs sed -i '' -e "s/<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" \/>/<Route component={L} path=\"$my_var\" routeName=\"L\" \/>/g"
```

Is there a way to input and get this script to run without having to input an escaped string?

Comment: Show us your actual file and the pattern to be replaced, rather than how you attempted and failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you became victim of what I call "bash-quoting-hell".

It seems that your escaping of `/` is eaten up before it is passed as argument to `sed`. Such problems are usually used by e.g. doubling the backslashs.

The following worked for me (in bash on cygwin):

```
$ read -p ' Input React route ' my_var
 Input React route \\/HomePage\\/

$ echo "<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" />" \
> | sed -e "s/<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" \/>/<Route component={L} path=\"$my_var\" routeName=\"L\" \/>/g"
<Route component={L} path="/HomePage/" routeName="L" />

$
```

This is not very convenient or user friendly (even if you yourself are the user). Therefore, I would add a pre-processing step:

```
$ read -p ' Input React route ' my_var
 Input React route /HomePage/

$ my_var=$(echo "$my_var" | sed -e 's/\//\\\//g')

$ echo "<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" />" \
> | sed -e "s/<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" \/>/<Route component={L} path=\"$my_var\" routeName=\"L\" \/>/g"
<Route component={L} path="/HomePage/" routeName="L" />

$
```

Btw. there is another, even simpler solution: The delimiter in `sed`s `s` command may be changed. (I used `#` in the following sample):

```
$ read -p ' Input React route ' my_var
 Input React route /HomePage/

$ echo "<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" />" \
> | sed -e "s#<Route component={P} path=\"p.html\" routeName=\"p\" \/>#<Route component={L} path=\"$my_var\" routeName=\"L\" \/>#g"
<Route component={L} path="/HomePage/" routeName="L" />

$
```

Answer (score 1):

`read` processes backslash escapes in the input - `\/` gets turned into `/` before being stored in `$my_var`.

You can avoid this by using `read -r`.

```
$ read my_var <<<'hello\/world'; echo "$my_var"
hello/world
$ read -r my_var <<<'hello\/world'; echo "$my_var"
hello\/world
```

If you have slashes in the component it will probably be useful to use a different separator in `sed` too, e.g.

```
sed -e "s:path=\"p.html\":path=\"$my_var\":g"
```

will work even if `$my_var` contains slashes, as long as it does not contain the character `:` which is now being used as the delimiter. You can choose other characters too, at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the delimiter:

```
read -p ' Input React route ' my_var
my_var=$(echo ${my_var} | sed -e 's_#_\\#_g')
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs sed -i '' \
       -e 's#<Route component={P} path="p.html" routeName="p" />#<Route component={L} path="$my_var" routeName="L" />#g'
```

The trick here is that you can change the delimiter to whatever you want. I also changed from using double-quotes in the shell to using single quotes. I think that makes things much more readable now!

The only thing is that you need to now dequote the # character, but again sed will do this quite nicely for you.